# HTML email with table and foreach

Tags: php, forms, algorithm, loops, foreach

I have a dynamic form where I can add or delete fields which is sent to a email. I made a html table in email message and I need to add a row depending on the number of added "products". There is pic of my idea (sorry for my paiting skill). [Pic of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yiufb.png)
There is html + php code. Should I translate it into english or not?

I hope you understand my problem. Could you help me please? I have tried a lot of different variations of loops but I can not do it. Thank you

```
<table name='contact_seller' style='border-collapse:collapse';> 
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style='width:auto;padding-right: 15px;'>typ dílu</th>
                    <th style='width:auto;padding-right: 15px;'>Počet kusů</th>
                    <th style='width:auto;padding-right: 15px;'>Číslo dílu</th>
                </tr>    
            </thead>
            <tbody>";
                foreach($typ_dilu['val'] as $key=>$val) { 
                    $message .="
                        <td>" . $val ."</td>";
                 } 
                 foreach($pocet_ks['val'] as $key=>$val) { 
                    $message .="
                        <td>" . $val ."</td>";
                 } 
                foreach($cislo_dilu['val'] as $key=>$val) { 
                    $message .="
                        <td>" . $val ."</td>";
                 } 

            $message .= "</tbody>
</table>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.vykupmotoru.cz/wp-content/themes/motory/scripts/script.js"></script>
<form action='#' class="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myform" id="myform" >

            <fieldset class="row2">
    <h3>Informace o dílu</h3>
     <input style="margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;" type="button" id="add" value="Přidat díl" /> 
     <input style="margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;" type="button" id="delete" value="Odebrat díl" /> 
               <table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1" style="max-width:960px; width:100%">
                   <tbody class="template" id="0">
                    <tr>
<td>
       <div class="form_item">
       <p class="form_label"><label>Typ dílu:</label></p>
       <p class="form_input"><span class=""><select name="typ_dilu[val][0]"><option value=""></option><option value="Vstřikovač">Vstřikovač</option><option value="Palivové čerpadlo">Palivové čerpadlo</option><option value="Turbo">Turbo</option><option value="EGR ventil">EGR ventil</option><option value="Startér">Startér</option><option value="Alternátor">Alternátor</option><option value="Klima kompresor">Klima kompresor</option><option value="Servo řízení">Servo řízení</option><option value="Převodovka">Převodovka</option><option value="Brzdový třemen">Brzdový třemen</option></select></span></p>
       <p></p>
       </div>     
      </td>
      
      <td>
       <div class="form_item">
       <p class="form_label"><label>Počet kusů:</label></p>
       <p class="form_input"><span class=""><input type="number" name="pocet_ks[val][0]"></span></p>
       <p></p>
       </div>
      </td>
       <td>
       <div class="form_item" >
       <p class="form_label"><label>Číslo dílu:</label></p>
       <p class="form_input"><span class=""><input type="text" name="cislo_dilu[val][0]"  required value="" size="40"></span></p>
       <p></p>
       </div>
        </td>
     </tr>
      
                    </tbody>
     
                </table>
    
    <div class="clear"></div>
            </fieldset>
   <div class="row_form">
    <div class="form_submit">
     <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Odeslat poptávku"></p>
     <p></p>
    </div>
   </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: You are missing a `<tr>`, that's why you get everything in rows.

Comment: No. I have tried to add <tr> on the different places but it wasnt working